# Clip a raster based on the extent of another raster in ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap, clip

I need to clip a raster to extract only the surface in common with another raster. How can I do that in ArcMap?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the Spatial Analyst extension, use the *Conditional* tool: `Con(ClipRaster, SourceRaster)`